# Loading Images from a Jarfile

Tags: java, image, class, jar, classloader

Alright so here is my problem and my question to you.....

I have a game in which it needs to load images from the jar file (all the images are packed into the jar file like so):
I first have the unzip of the jar file:
[image: Unziped Jar File]

Then it goes to:
[image: cards folder]

Then inside each of those folder i have something that looks like this:
[image: what the other folders look like also]

Now reminder above is the Jarfile GameClient.jar unziped and you see where the cards are in it.

So here is my code for trying to load each and every one of those images into memory

```
    private void addCardsAndChangeSize() throws IOException
{
    String tempString;
    ImageIcon tempIcon;
    allCards.clear();
    ClassLoader cldr = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    URL imageURL;

    for(int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < clubs.length; x++)
        {
            tempString = all[i][x];
            tempString = "/cards/"+cardFolders[i]+"/"+tempString;
            imageURL = cldr.getResource(tempString);
            tempIcon = resizeImage(new ImageIcon(imageURL),70,70,false);
            tempString = all[i][x];
            tempIcon.setDescription(tempString);
            allCards.add(tempIcon);
        }
    }
    backCard = resizeImage(new ImageIcon(cldr.getResource(back)),70,70,false);
}
```

So i call that in the contructor to load all the images into an ArrayList here is the whole class if you want to know what i do.

```
package global;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Cards
{
private ImageIcon backCard = new ImageIcon("cards/backCard.jpg");
private String back = "/cards/backCard.jpg";
private String[] cardFolders = {
        "clubs","diamonds","hearts","spades"
};
private String[] clubs = {
                              "aceClubs.jpg","eightClubs.jpg","fiveClubs.jpg","fourClubs.jpg","jackClubs.jpg",
        "kingClubs.jpg","nineClubs.jpg","queenClubs.jpg","sevenClubs.jpg","sixClubs.jpg",
        "tenClubs.jpg","threeClubs.jpg","twoClubs.jpg"
};
private String[] diamonds = {
        "aceDia.jpg","eightDia.jpg","fiveDia.jpg","fourDia.jpg","jackDia.jpg","kingDia.jpg",
        "nineDia.jpg","queenDia.jpg","sevenDia.jpg","sixDia.jpg","tenDia.jpg","threeDia.jpg",
        "twoDia.jpg"
};
private String[] hearts = {
        "aceHearts.jpg","eightHearts.jpg","fiveHearts.jpg","fourHearts.jpg","jackHearts.jpg",
        "kingHearts.jpg","nineHearts.jpg","queenHearts.jpg","sevenHearts.jpg","sixHearts.jpg",
        "tenHearts.jpg","threeHearts.jpg","twoHearts.jpg"
};
private String[] spades = {
        "aceSpades.jpg","eightSpades.jpg","fiveSpades.jpg","fourSpades.jpg","jackSpades.jpg",
        "kingSpades.jpg","nineSpades.jpg","queenSpades.jpg","sevenSpades.jpg","sixSpades.jpg",
        "tenSpades.jpg","threeSpades.jpg","twoSpades.jpg"
};
private String[][] all = {
        clubs,diamonds,hearts,spades
};
private ArrayList<ImageIcon> allCards = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();

public Cards()
{
    try
    {
        addCardsAndChangeSize();
        shuffle();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {e.printStackTrace();}
}

/**
 * @param x Cards name with extension
 * @return Face Value of Card
 */
public static int getFaceValue(String x)
{
    int face = 0;
    switch(x)
    {
        case "aceClubs.jpg":
        case "aceDia.jpg":
        case "aceHearts.jpg":
        case "aceSpades.jpg":
            face = 1;
            break;
        case "eightClubs.jpg":
        case "eightDia.jpg":
        case "eightHearts.jpg":
        case "eightSpades.jpg":
            face = 8;
            break;
        case "fiveClubs.jpg":
        case "fiveDia.jpg":
        case "fiveHearts.jpg":
        case "fiveSpades.jpg":
            face = 5;
            break;
        case "fourClubs.jpg":
        case "fourDia.jpg":
        case "fourHearts.jpg":
        case "fourSpades.jpg":
            face = 4;
            break;
        case "jackClubs.jpg":
        case "jackDia.jpg":
        case "jackHearts.jpg":
        case "jackSpades.jpg":
        case "kingClubs.jpg":
        case "kingDia.jpg":
        case "kingHearts.jpg":
        case "kingSpades.jpg":
        case "queenClubs.jpg":
        case "queenDia.jpg":
        case "queenHearts.jpg":
        case "queenSpades.jpg":
        case "tenClubs.jpg":
        case "tenDia.jpg":
        case "tenHearts.jpg":
        case "tenSpades.jpg":
            face = 10;
            break;
        case "twoClubs.jpg":
        case "twoDia.jpg":
        case "twoHearts.jpg":
        case "twoSpades.jpg":
            face = 2;
            break;
        case "threeClubs.jpg":
        case "threeDia.jpg":
        case "threeHearts.jpg":
        case "threeSpades.jpg":
            face = 3;
            break;
        case "sixClubs.jpg":
        case "sixDia.jpg":
        case "sixHearts.jpg":
        case "sixSpades.jpg":
            face = 6;
            break;
        case "sevenClubs.jpg":
        case "sevenDia.jpg":
        case "sevenHearts.jpg":
        case "sevenSpades.jpg":
            face = 7;
            break;
        case "nineClubs.jpg":
        case "nineDia.jpg":
        case "nineHearts.jpg":
        case "nineSpades.jpg":
            face = 9;
            break;
    }
    return face;
}

//shuffles all the cards in the deck
private void shuffle()
{
    long seed = System.nanoTime();
    Collections.shuffle(allCards, new Random(seed));
}

/**
 * Chooses a card at random from the deck. Also removes that card when chosen
 * @return randomly chosen card
 */
public ImageIcon getRandomCard()
{
    int index = ((int)Math.random() * allCards.size());
    return allCards.remove(index);
}

/**
 * @return Image of the back of a card
 */
public ImageIcon getBackCard()
{return backCard;}

public static ImageIcon parseImage(String x)
{
    if(x.contains("Dia"))
        return new ImageIcon("cards/diamonds/"+x);
    else
        if(x.contains("Clubs"))
            return new ImageIcon("cards/clubs/"+x);
        else
            if(x.contains("Hearts"))
                return new ImageIcon("cards/hearts/"+x);
            else
                if(x.contains("Spades"))
                    return new ImageIcon("cards/spades/"+x);
    return null;
}

//adds all the cards and adds a description to them loaded into memory
private void addCardsAndChangeSize() throws IOException
{
    String tempString;
    ImageIcon tempIcon;
    allCards.clear();
    ClassLoader cldr = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    URL imageURL;

    for(int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < clubs.length; x++)
        {
            tempString = all[i][x];
            tempString = "/cards/"+cardFolders[i]+"/"+tempString;
            imageURL = cldr.getResource(tempString);
            tempIcon = resizeImage(new ImageIcon(imageURL),70,70,false);
            tempString = all[i][x];
            tempIcon.setDescription(tempString);
            allCards.add(tempIcon);
        }
    }
    backCard = resizeImage(new ImageIcon(cldr.getResource(back)),70,70,false);
}

//resizes images
public ImageIcon resizeImage(ImageIcon imageIcon, int width, int height, boolean max) 
{
    Image image = imageIcon.getImage();
    Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(-1, height, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    int width1 = newimg.getWidth(null);
    if ((max && width1 > width) || (!max && width1 < width))
        newimg = image.getScaledInstance(width, -1, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    return new ImageIcon(newimg);
}
```

}

I keep getting null pointer exception on the `tempIcon = resizeImage(new ImageIcon(imageURL),70,70,false);`

Can anyone tell me why this isn't loading the images properly? Reminder i am pre-loading them into memory. My question is not how to make this better i am just simply asking what am i doing wrong with the class loader and stuff like that......

I am somewhat new at java and i know some of this code will look horrible to you but please again i am not asking how to make this code "pro" im just looking for the explanation why its giving me null.

Thanks!

P.S. If you need more pictures of info or w.e. i will try to put that up right away

Comment: Java is case sensitive when reading resources from Jar files. Are you sure that the file extension is '.jpg' and not '.JPG' ?

Comment: It is .jpg not .JPG but thanks for that for further use

Comment: Which card exactly is causing the problem? Is it the first card you try to load? There might be a typo somewhere in your big list of card filenames. You should check `imageURL` for null and if so throw an exception that gives you the filename that caused the problem. That might reveal the cause.

Comment: The first one i try to load. Also there are no typos going through it that was my first attempt at a solution.

Comment: System.out.println(imageURL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the `getResource` of `Class`, not `ClassLoader`. The `getResource` method in `Class` does useful transformations on the path before giving it to the `ClassLoader` version of the method, like deciding if the path is relative to the class or absolute, and so `ClassLoader` doesn't expect to see things like `/` at the start of the path. You can see this clearly in the [`getResource` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Yes it can (*"see things like / at the start of the path"*), this makes the difference between and absolute path based on the class path and a relative path from the class loading it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Maybe some ClassLoaders can handle that, but for some reason Class.getResource removes the initial '/'. It's probably a good reason.

Comment: Okay, missed the point about `Classloader.getResource(...)` and `getClass().getResource(...);`

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `cldr.getResource(tempString);` does not return object but null. Then, something is wrong with tempString. Classloader cannot find this file, so returns null.

Change `tempString = "/cards/"+cardFolders[i]+"/"+tempString;`

To `tempString = "cards/"+cardFolders[i]+"/"+tempString;`

Comment: I agree with the first half, but don't see how changing the path from an absolute to relative reference will help...unless the original path is wrong...just saying...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have just written sample code and it seems to be difference for ClassLoader if path starts from "/" - possibly it looks for file in only one directory - unfortunately not the jar package root.

Comment: AFAIK `getClass().getResource()` will allow you to define the difference between a relative and absolute path, where as `ClassLoader#getResource` will always be absolute from the context of the classpath. You might be able to add using `getClass().getResource(...`)` instead of `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(...)` instead

Comment: Thanks :) anyway `/` as a first character in classloader's `getResources()` does not well. Just check it out - it's 2 lines of code.

Comment: Already did ;) - Missing the difference `ClassLoader.getResource` and `getClass().getResource()` ;)

Answer (score 0):

So i found out the solution i still don't quite understand why this is the answer but here ya go.

This is the revised code and works fine

```
private void addCardsAndChangeSize() throws Exception
{
    String tempString;
    ImageIcon tempIcon;
    allCards.clear();
    URL imageURL;

    for(int i = 0; i < all.length; i++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < clubs.length; x++)
        {
            tempString = all[i][x];
            tempString = "/cards/"+cardFolders[i]+"/"+tempString;
            imageURL = this.getClass().getResource(tempString);
            System.out.println(tempString);
            System.out.println(imageURL == null);
            tempIcon = resizeImage(new ImageIcon(imageURL),70,70,false);
            tempString = all[i][x];
            tempIcon.setDescription(tempString);
            allCards.add(tempIcon);
        }
    }
    backCard = resizeImage(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(back)),70,70,false);
}
```

You have to have that "/cards/"   and also you this.getClass().getResource(String res);

Thanks for all your help guys!